# Why do my answers and comments keep getting silently deleted?

Tags: support, comments

I've nearly stopped using this site because my answers, or the question I'm answering, simply disappears without a trace. At this point I only use comments, since answers are no longer worth the time investment. However my comments are also disappearing now.

Am I doing something wrong? Are my comments too long? Is there a way to view the reason they were removed?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. On which site(s) is this happening? If you haven't already done so, you should ask in the corresponding meta of those sites instead as this Meta site is for software or other aspects of the entire set of SE set of sites. Also, note you can view your answers deleted within the past 2 months by clicking on the Answer tab in your Activity page, then click the "recently deleted answers" link at the bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 3):

This started off as a comment, but I felt like it was getting too long.

Unfortunately, I can't speak as to why your answers are getting deleted. Worldbuilding is the only SE site you're active on where I have enough rep to see your deleted answers, and I'd have to go and track them down first. If your answers are getting deleted through the VLQ queue, then you *should* receive a canned comment from one of the people who voted to delete, explaining what was wrong with it (though admittedly, this doesn't always happen).

If a question you're trying to answer is getting closed and deleted while you're typing, it's usually a sign that the question is VLQ and/or off-topic, and you shouldn't have been trying to answer it in the first place. I appreciate your enthusiasm, but answering those sorts of questions encourages people to ask more of them. (I also appreciate the irony that this was closed a minute after I answered it!)

As for comments, those are second-class citizens, and if they're not directly asking for clarifications or suggesting improvements, they're liable to getting deleted at any given time. Ironically, this includes your most recent comment on Worldbuilding.SE:

[image]

This is almost certainly going to get deleted because it's a meta-discussion and not related to the actual question.

I do sympathise with you, and I wish I could do more to help. If you could provide links to any of your deleted answers on Worldbuilding.SE, I could look through them and explain what might be wrong with them.